# Editing local file after hitting button

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to make a comment section for a locally hosted site, basically I am trying to make it so when you hit the submit button, it checks for a existing file, if it exists, then it will edit it, and put the comment into it, if it doesn't exist, then it'll create the file, and save the data, I'm trying to save it as JSON if possible, any ideas?

The only things I can find are to let the visitor save to the computer, which isn't what I'm trying to do, I want the site to only be able to access it. And I'm trying to not set up a server if possible.

Comment: please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as this is not a good question for stackoverflow.

Comment: Would this not mean it only works for 1 user? Other users can't see the comments, as you store it locally? If thats the case, could you not use `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need some kind of backend server to do that since JavaScript runs on the client side. I can only recommend taking a look at a NodeJS http server that changes the files according to GET or POST requests or using said GET and POST requests in combination with a server-side PHP script.